# WordPress 'post_name' in posts table duplicated

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to receive all portfolio entries from the database. I want to list this and also link the WordPress path to it. This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT id, post_title, post_name FROM 1bncopo2_posts WHERE post_type='portfolio';
```

post_title could be the following:

1. Mercedes-Benz AMG C63
2. Mercedes-Benz S500
3. BMW 650i XDrive

and now post_name for the first entry of the above list is `mercedes-benz-amg-c63`. However, I found that in my database table, multiple portfolio vehicles (even vehicles by BMW, etc.) have `post_name` set to `mercedes-benz-amg-c63`. My idea was to generate the URL to the portfolio item using `post_name` as an appendix to the wordpress path. TO BE CLEAR: This is going to be a seperate application reading from the WordPress installation's database and trying to make up the corresponding links to the portfolio items.

Now that `post_name` is not `UNIQUE` or something I could use, I have two questions:

1. Why would the WP database allow for duplicated `post_names`?
2. How can I get the post (portfolio)'s URL, if not by `post_name`?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to repeat the link, if you see the link from the beginning you will find it different.

If this post `(mercedes-benz-amg-c63)` for custom post type called `(portfolio)` you see URL like:

```
www.domain.com/portfolio/mercedes-benz-amg-c63
```

But if its post type (post) you see URL like:

```
www.domain.com/mercedes-benz-amg-c63
```

Then as you see the URL not duplicated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I don't think this answers the question, which is (given the fact that `mercedes-benz-amg-c63` is set multiple times for different cars, for whatever reason) how to get the URL (which is like `example.com/portfolio/slug-goes-here`) because `post_name` isn't unique.

Comment: there are different between (example.com/portfolio/slug-goes-here) and (example.com/car/slug-goes-here) and (example.com/slug-goes-here)

Comment: I'm amazed by how much you're saying that has nothing to do with the question asked!